# T-SQL nested count case

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to do an interval count from a single table in SQL Server which has multiple attributes I would like to use.

The table named [Stats] that I'm working with looks like the following:

| Id | FileID | PlayerName | GameRuleApplied | GameMap | GameScore | TimeOfExitGame |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| int | int | string | string | int | int | DateTime |

The idea is that the query should return a table like the following:

| Year/Month | Interval | Counter |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023/01 | 0-10 | x |
| 2023/01 | 11-30 | y |
| 2022/12 | 0-10 | z |

I have made the below T-SQL query to get every single player and their unique games counted.

```
select count(p) from (
select PlayerName as p, COUNT(distinct FileID) as g
from [dbo].[Stats]
where GameRuleApplied = 'asb' and GameMap = 100
and GameScore > 0
and TimeOfTheExitTransit >= '2023-01-01 00:00:00.000' and TimeOfTheExitTransit <= '2023-01-31 23:59:59.999'
group by PlayerName) as t
```

When I try to do a nested case count count on the already existing count the code breaks.
When I remove the outer select then the SQL do just as I want. I just wish for it to continue its counting based on the inner counting.

The end goal is for having the Year/Month go perhaps 5-6 months back in time starting from last months.

The interval case is supposed to be something like:
How many players have played between 0-10 and 11-30 rounds of games and scored more than 0, played the specific map with the applied rule set

Comment: Can you share some input data

Comment: Do you need to show all Year/months, even if Counter is 0?

Comment: I can share input data - i just need to find a place to put it . If the counter is 0 the year /month and be left out. 

There are multiple values in GameRulesApplied and GameMaps. The query should only look for these very specific once.

Distinct on fileID is important because a fileID in the stats table will sadly not be unique and be there more than once (with all the same data on the rows). 

The stats table contains a "fase" attribute that is not relevant for the question which is why i have left it out 

Comment: Not at all clear what your objective is here but part of the issue is that you are using string literals as column names. Then when you reference that column in your outer query it thinks you are trying to count another string literal. Get rid of those string literals. Even though it won't solve the issue it will make the problem far less confusing and strange.

Comment: You also have some challenging code going on here. You are using in with a single value, why not simply =? You are using between with datetimes. This is [very problematic](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common). You seem to be storing numbers as strings (GameMap).

Comment: Thank you for your comment Sean - I think you are right. I my hurry of making this post I just saw that my end statement of the post was kinda wrong.

The main goal is really to try sort in intervals for each month going like 6 months back in time starting from last month like how many players have played the specific map with the specific rules applied and scored more than 0 in that game. where the game was played within that month

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you overcomplicate it a bit, why not something like this:

```sql
select CONCAT(YEAR(TimeOfExitGame), '/', MONTH(TimeOfExitGame))
, s.ScoreInterval, COUNT(DISTINCT FileID)
FROM [Stats]
CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT case when GameScore BETWEEN 0 and 10 then '0-10' when GameScope BETWEEN 11 AND 30 THEN '11-30' END AS ScoreInterval
) s
GROUP BY CONCAT(YEAR(TimeOfExitGame), '/', MONTH(TimeOfExitGame))
, s.ScoreInterval
```

You create an interval field depending on the score and then just group by time of finish.

EDIT:
Query #2 which tries to group by number of games:

```sql
select gamePeriod, CASE WHEN gameRounds BETWEEN 0 AND 10 THEN '0-10'
WHEN gameRounds BETWEEN 11 and 30 THEN '11-30' ELSE '>30' END
, GameRuleApplied, GameMap, COUNT(*)
from (
  select PlayerName as p, COUNT(distinct FileID) as gameRounds
  , GameRuleApplied, GameMap,Playername, CONCAT(YEAR(TimeOfExitGame), 
  '/', MONTH(TimeOfExitGame)) AS gamePeriod
  from [dbo].[Stats]
  WHERE GameScore > 0
  group by GameRuleApplied, GameMap,Playername, 
  CONCAT(YEAR(TimeOfExitGame), '/', MONTH(TimeOfExitGame))
) x
GROUP BY CASE WHEN gameRounds BETWEEN 0 AND 10 THEN '0-10'
WHEN gameRounds BETWEEN 11 and 30 THEN '11-30' ELSE '>30' END
, GameRuleApplied, GameMap
```

Comment: This looks amazing - can i add some of the where statements in the select case - to make sure that it only have counted the distinct fileIds where the "wheres" are true?

Comment: When you put the field in select, it must be part of group by or to be inside aggregate function. So yes you can, as long as you follow the rule

Comment: It might ruin the aggregate though

Comment: I updated my end statement in my post - i saw that i written that i wanted to count the gamescore - what i really want to do is to make intervals on how many round of games players have had in a specific map with a specific rule set and where they have scored more than 0

Comment: Ok,that's a bit different question... But i guess you can use this to solve your issue as well. You already know how to use subselects, so in the inner you calculate count of rounds grouped by map and rule, and in the outer you do the case when counter thingy

Comment: Gotta admit that i'm rather struggling with sql or programming in generel - new in this field!

I'll see if i can wrap my head around your first query and see if i can figure out how to modify it to make sure that it reflects the right question.

Based on other comments I have learned that there are more basic issues related to my first posted sql query eg the between issue 

Comment: That's alright, we all gotta start somewhere! I've added another version which kinda tries to do what i was talking about. Maybe it's a bit simplier to understand. Good luck!